# Doesn't select the Right option in dropdown

Tags: jasmine, protractor, dropdown

Protractor select the wrong option in dropdown.
I have to:
select the first dropdown to open another dropdown (in my situation: select Payment Method (1st dropdown) to open the 2nd dropdown - available credit cards): 
The IMPORTANT moment: if the 1st dropdown has a default value - the 2nd dropdown CAN NOT be visible.

My piece of code had different variation:

```
let paymentDropdown = element(by.name("payment-method"));
let dynamicBlock = $$(".dynamic").first();
let useThisCardButton = element(by.name("do-add-payment-method»));
let paymentConfigBlock = element(by.id("payment-config-container"));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(paymentDropdown), 5000);
$("#payment-method-0 > option:nth-child(2)").click();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dynamicBlock), 5000);
useThisCardButton.click();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(paymentConfigBlock), 5000);
```

So, I’ve tried for the first dropdown:

```
1. $("#payment-method-0 > option:nth-child(2)").click();
2. element(by.name("payment-method"))
    .all(by.tagName('option'))
    .get(1)
    .click(); 
3. element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Credit Card')).click();
4. element(by.name("payment-method")).$('[value="cc"]').click();
```

Html is:

```
<select name="payment-method" id="payment-method-0" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="0">Select Payment Method</option>
<option value="cc">Credit Card</option>                    
</select>
```

And Nothing! I don’t know how does it work, but the 1st dropdown has Default Value, and the 2nd dropdown is VISIBLE! Then I click on «Use this method» button and got Fail!
1 test from 10 tests choose the right 1st value, so test passed. But other 9 trials are failed. Why? How to do it correct and how to be sure that it will select the right option?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one. Here you can select the values **without opening the drop down**.

```
var firstDrop = element(by.css('#payment-method-0'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(firstDrop), 5000);
firstDrop.sendKeys('Credit Card');
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dynamicBlock), 5000);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: It works as the other my varians. I noticed, that when I use Sleep:
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(firstDrop), 5000);
    browser.sleep(5000);
    firstDrop.sendKeys('Credit Card');

Everything is ok - the needest option is chosen. But without Sleep - it choose the Wrong option. And I can't understand why..

Comment: since you are selecting the value without opening the dropdown we must consider wait for sometime to get the dropdown options loaded. Do mark the answer correct if it resolved your issue.